# Android Facebook key hashes not adding in developer account

Tags: android, facebook

Ok i have got multiple problems with key hashes.

- Is there a limit to add the number of key hashes on FB developer account? I am unable to add the 5 th one?
- I developed an application on PC A and generated a hash key -> added it to the application account on FB. Every thing works fine on my TAB. When i created the APK file and installed it on another TAB it started showing me the "Invalid key HASH" , It shows another key xxxxxx and says it should be added in developer account? From where this key came ?? When i tried adding that key my FB acount does not take it . Its something like yf6c/xxxxxxxxxxx.

Any inputs?

Comment: Hi @Nbajam, With my experience the same project if U generate apk files with different systems, then FB/Google it won't show ur expected o/p. Because in the first system ur generating harsh key is different to second system.

Answer (score 1):

The key hashes depend on the signing certificate being used.If you are using different machines to generate apk's the key hash would be different for debug builds.
You should use the same debug.keystore to sign your application

Answer (score 0):

OK, the solution to the problem was to add key in Facebook developer account. It worked!!